Mind Map in Fluttter
I making a mind map widget in flutter. I want to give curves to some arrows which connects the nodes it there any solution to curves to these arrows or give me code after solve this issue. The nodes are are pressable which navigate to pages.
i will try everything i know now i need help.
enter image description here sample image
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:ouditor/initialization/chart_of_accounts/chart_of_accounts.dart';
import 'package:ouditor/modules/financial_reports/pages/profit_loss_reports_pages/profit_loss_by_inventory_item_page.dart';
import 'package:ouditor/modules/vendor_relations/pages/billing_document_table_pages/product_refund_vendor_table_page.dart';
import 'package:ouditor/modules/vendor_relations/pages/billing_document_table_pages/purchase_bill_table_page.dart';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:ouditor/modules/vendor_relations/pages/billing_document_table_pages/purchase_estimate_table_page.dart';
import 'package:ouditor/modules/vendor_relations/pages/billing_document_table_pages/purchase_order_table_page.dart';
import 'package:ouditor/modules/vendor_relations/pages/billing_document_table_pages/purchase_receipt_table_page.dart';
import 'package:ouditor/modules/vendor_relations/pages/create_payment_transaction_pages/create_make_payment_vendor_page.dart';
import 'package:ouditor/navigation/page_router.dart';

class VendorMindMap extends StatelessWidget {
  VendorMindMap({super.key});

  final ChartOfAccounts selectedKey = ChartOfAccounts.accountsPayable;

  final List<CustomArrow> arrows = [
    CustomArrow(
        fromNode: 0,
        toNode: 1,
        label: '',
        labelOffsetXFactor: -0.2,
        labelOffsetYFactor: -0.01,
        rotationAngle: 0.0),
    CustomArrow(
        fromNode: 1,
        toNode: 2,
        label: '',
        labelOffsetXFactor: -0.2,
        labelOffsetYFactor: -0.01,
        rotationAngle: 0.0),
    CustomArrow(
        fromNode: 3,
        toNode: 2,
        label: '',
        labelOffsetXFactor: -0.2,
        labelOffsetYFactor: -0.01,
        rotationAngle: 0.0),
    CustomArrow(
        fromNode: 4,
        toNode: 3,
        label: '',
        labelOffsetXFactor: -0.2,
        labelOffsetYFactor: -0.01,
        rotationAngle: 0.0),
    CustomArrow(
        fromNode: 5,
        toNode: 2,
        label: '',
        labelOffsetXFactor: -0.2,
        labelOffsetYFactor: -0.01,
        rotationAngle: 0.0),
    CustomArrow(
        fromNode: 3,
        toNode: 5,
        label: '',
        labelOffsetXFactor: -0.2,
        labelOffsetYFactor: -0.01,
        rotationAngle: 0.0,
        ),
    CustomArrow(
        fromNode: 6,
        toNode: 0,
        label: '',
        labelOffsetXFactor: -0.2,
        labelOffsetYFactor: -0.01,
        rotationAngle: 0.0),
    CustomArrow(
        fromNode: 6,
        toNode: 7,
        label: '',
        labelOffsetXFactor: -0.2,
        labelOffsetYFactor: -0.01,
        rotationAngle: 0.0),
    CustomArrow(
        fromNode: 0,
        toNode: 7,
        label: '',
        labelOffsetXFactor: -0.2,
        labelOffsetYFactor: -0.01,
        rotationAngle: 0.0),
    CustomArrow(
        fromNode: 7,
        toNode: 8,
        label: '',
        labelOffsetXFactor: -0.2,
        labelOffsetYFactor: -0.01,
        rotationAngle: 0.0),
    CustomArrow(
        fromNode: 1,
        toNode: 8,
        label: '',
        labelOffsetXFactor: -0.2,
        labelOffsetYFactor: -0.01,
        rotationAngle: 0.0),
    CustomArrow(
        fromNode: 2,
        toNode: 9,
        label: '',
        labelOffsetXFactor: -0.2,
        labelOffsetYFactor: -0.01,
        rotationAngle: 0.0),
    CustomArrow(
        fromNode: 9,
        toNode: 4,
        label: '',
        labelOffsetXFactor: -0.2,
        labelOffsetYFactor: -0.01,
        rotationAngle: 0.0),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<MindMapNode> nodes = [
      MindMapNode(
          title: 'Purchase Estimate', page: const PurchaseEstimateTablePage()),
      MindMapNode(title: 'Purchase Bill', page: const PurchaseBillTablePage()),
      MindMapNode(
        title: 'Account Payabel',
        page: ListTile(
          title: Text(selectedKey.toString()),
          subtitle:
              Text(chartOfAccountsEnumMap[selectedKey] ?? 'No value found'),
        ),
      ),
      MindMapNode(
          title: 'Make Payment', page: const CreateMakePaymentVendorPage()),
      MindMapNode(title: 'BankCash', page: const PurchaseBillTablePage()),
      MindMapNode(title: 'Vendor Expense', page: const PurchaseBillTablePage()),
      MindMapNode(
          title: 'Purchase Order', page: const PurchaseOrderTablePage()),
      MindMapNode(
          title: 'Purchase Receipt', page: const PurchaseReceiptTablePage()),
      MindMapNode(
          title: 'Inventory', page: const ProfitLossByInventoryItemPage()),
      MindMapNode(
          title: 'Refund Payment', page: const ProductRefundVendorTablePage()),
    ];

    final screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    List<Offset> positions = _calculateNodePositions();

    return Scaffold(
      body: Card(
        elevation: 8,
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            CustomPaint(
              size: Size(screenSize.width, screenSize.height),
              painter: MindMapPainter(nodes, arrows, positions, screenSize),
            ),
            ...List.generate(nodes.length, (index) {
              return Positioned(
                left: positions[index].dx - 75,
                top: positions[index].dy - 25,
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    PageRouter.push(context: context, route: nodes[index].page);
                    // Navigator.push(
                    //   context,
                    //   MaterialPageRoute(
                    //       builder: (context) => nodes[index].page),
                    // );
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    width: 150,
                    height: 50,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                    ),
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        nodes[index].title,
                        style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Offset> _calculateNodePositions() {
    // Manually specify positions for each node
    return [
      const Offset(100, 235), //Purchase Estimate "node 0"
      const Offset(350, 235), //Purchase Bill "node 1"
      const Offset(600, 235), //Accounts Payable "node 2"
      const Offset(850, 235), // Make Payment "node 3"
      const Offset(1100, 235), // BankCash "node 4"
      const Offset(600, 100), // Vendor Expense "node 5"
      const Offset(100, 370), // Purchase Order "node 6"
      const Offset(350, 370), // Purchase Receipt "node 7"
      const Offset(600, 370), // Inventory "node 8"
      const Offset(850, 370), // Refund Payment "node 9"
    ];
  }
}

class MindMapNode {
  final String title;
  final Widget page;

  MindMapNode({required this.title, required this.page});
}

class CustomArrow {
  final int fromNode;
  final int toNode;
  final String label;
  final double labelOffsetXFactor;
  final double labelOffsetYFactor;
  final double rotationAngle;
 

  CustomArrow({
    required this.fromNode,
    required this.toNode,
    required this.label,
    this.labelOffsetXFactor = 0,
    this.labelOffsetYFactor = 0,
    this.rotationAngle = 0,
   
  });
}

class MindMapPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final List<MindMapNode> nodes;
  final List<CustomArrow> arrows;
  final List<Offset> positions;
  final Size screenSize;

  MindMapPainter(this.nodes, this.arrows, this.positions, this.screenSize);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paintArrow = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.black
      ..strokeWidth = 2;

    for (var arrow in arrows) {
      drawArrow(canvas, paintArrow, positions[arrow.fromNode],
          positions[arrow.toNode], arrow);
    }
  }

  void drawArrow(
      Canvas canvas, Paint paint, Offset start, Offset end, CustomArrow arrow) {
    // Calculate the arrow's adjusted endpoint to be at the container boundary
    double arrowWidth = 150; // Width of the node container
    double arrowHeight = 50; // Height of the node container

    // Calculate the normalized direction vector
    double dx = end.dx - start.dx;
    double dy = end.dy - start.dy;
    double length = sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    double normX = dx / length;
    double normY = dy / length;

    // Adjust the endpoint to the boundary of the rectangle
    Offset adjustedEnd = Offset(
      end.dx - (arrowWidth / 2 * normX),
      end.dy - (arrowHeight / 2 * normY),
    );

     // Draw the main line of the arrow
    canvas.drawLine(start, adjustedEnd, paint);

    // Calculate the angle for the arrowhead
    double arrowSize = 10;
    double angle = atan2(dy, dx);
    Offset arrowEnd1 = Offset(adjustedEnd.dx - arrowSize * cos(angle - pi / 6),
        adjustedEnd.dy - arrowSize * sin(angle - pi / 6));
    Offset arrowEnd2 = Offset(adjustedEnd.dx - arrowSize * cos(angle + pi / 6),
        adjustedEnd.dy - arrowSize * sin(angle + pi / 6));

    // Draw the arrowhead
    canvas.drawLine(adjustedEnd, arrowEnd1, paint);
    canvas.drawLine(adjustedEnd, arrowEnd2, paint);

    // Draw the label at the specified offset
    drawLabel(canvas, arrow, start, adjustedEnd);
  }

  void drawLabel(Canvas canvas, CustomArrow arrow, Offset start, Offset end) {
    double midX =
        (start.dx + end.dx) / 2 + (screenSize.width * arrow.labelOffsetXFactor);
    double midY = (start.dy + end.dy) / 2 +
        (screenSize.height * arrow.labelOffsetYFactor);

    // Create a text painter with responsive font size
    double fontSize = 12; // Static font size
    TextPainter textPainter = TextPainter(
      text: TextSpan(
          text: arrow.label,
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: fontSize)),
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
    );
    textPainter.layout();

    // Save the current canvas state
    canvas.save();

    // Move the canvas to the midpoint and rotate it
    canvas.translate(midX, midY);
    canvas.rotate(arrow.rotationAngle);

    // Draw the label centered at the new position
    textPainter.paint(
        canvas, Offset(-textPainter.width / 2, -textPainter.height / 2));

    // Restore the canvas state
    canvas.restore();
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}


Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
